# Opening Keynote files in uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I'm very new to objective-c, but I've learned how to create a uiwebview. I'm trying to open a keynote file in uiwebview using this code from Apple's dev site:

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

// Calling -loadDocument:inView:
[self loadDocument:@"mydocument.key.zip" inView:self.myWebview];
```

However, I'm getting the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'self'" Do I need to declare the identifier 'self' in WebViewController.h? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not, self is basically "this" in Java and other languages. Looks to me that myWebView is not a property and therefore does not have a getter, and self.myWebview is trying to get the getter. You could try:

```
[self loadDocument:@"mydocument.key.zip" inView:myWebview];
```

Other possibility that comes to mind is that the method implementation for loadDocument is after the call to the method and not before. This really is not a problem unless you don't have the method declared in your interface like this:

```
@interface myClass

- (void)loadDocument:(NSString *)sender inView:(UIWebView) webView;
```